# Logback : add new log with different level for Dev and Prod environment

Tags: java, spring, log4j, logback, spring-logback

I want to add new log file myNewLog.log, I wont to use different logger level in different environment without infect the existing log. The levels of the dev environment and the prod environment are mentioned in below description :

1. for Dev env

   - level error is active
   - level info is active
   - level debug is active (default level for the dev)

I added a new appender myNewLog and I setted the default level to DEBUG then I create a 3 loggers with name myNewLog each one has a different level.

**logback.xml for the dev env:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="2 seconds">
    <property resource="logback.properties" />

    <appender name="apiLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/mylog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/mylog.log.%d{yyyy.MM.dd}</fileNamePattern>

            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="myNewLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/myNewLog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/myNewLog%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>


    <logger name="apiLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="apiLog" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

2. for Prod env

   - level error is active (default level for the prod)
   - level info will be activated in needs
   - level debug is deactivated

I added a new appender myNewLog and I setted the default level to ERROR then I create a 3 loggers with name myNewLog each one has a different level.

**logback.xml for Prod env :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="2 seconds">
    <property resource="logback.properties" />

    <appender name="apiLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/mylog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/mylog.log.%d{yyyy.MM.dd}</fileNamePattern>

            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="myNewLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/myNewLog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/myNewLog%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>


    <logger name="apiLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="apiLog" />
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="ERROR" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**My questions are :**

- how can I manage log level for each environment ?
- can I manage the levels for the 2 environments in one logback file ?

Answer (score 0):

1. in application.yml, use different profile for each environment. and define level var my.log.level

```yaml
logging:
  config: classpath:logback.xml

--- #dev
spring:
  profiles:
  - dev

my:
  log:
    level: DEBUG

--- #prod
spring:
  profiles:
  - prod

my:
  log:
    level: ERROR
```

2. in logback.xml use "<springProperty>" to import this var.
   **if logback.xml is not effective, please rename it to logback-spring.xml to try again**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="2 seconds">

    <!-- import var from application.yml -->
    <springProperty scope="context" name="logLevel" source="my.log.level" defaultValue="INFO"/>

    <property resource="logback.properties" />

    <appender name="apiLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/mylog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/mylog.log.%d{yyyy.MM.dd}</fileNamePattern>

            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="myNewLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/myNewLog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${APPL_FULL_PATH}/logs/myNewLog%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${logLevel}</level>
        </filter>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>${logLevel}</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>


    <logger name="apiLog" level="INFO" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="apiLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="myNewLog" level="INFO" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="myNewLog" />
    </logger>
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>



</configuration>
```

3. use --spring.profiles.active to run. for instance, use dev to run

```sh
java -jar [mvn-created-jar-file-name] --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition, it's not a spring boot project I don' have an application.yml also I can't change logback.xml  to logback-spring.xml

Comment: if not using spring-boot, please use env variable to define "my.log.level". in logback.xml, <level>${my.log.level:-INFO</level>. INFO is default value. Your application started way is like: java -Dmy.log.level=DEBUG  -jar [your-jar]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to override the logkback.xml for different environemnts. I started application with different vm options. For instance

for dev:

```
-Dlogging.config=file:my_path/dev/logback.xml
```

for prod:

```
-Dlogging.config=file:my_path/prd/logback.xml
```